# How to get all values from ForeignKey relation in loop?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a next models: `Order`, `OrderItem`

```
class Order(models.Model):
    pass


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order, related_name='order_item',
        verbose_name=_('order'), null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        limit_choices_to={'enabled': True}
    )
    product_item = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, related_name='order_item',
        verbose_name=_('product item'), null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        limit_choices_to={'enabled': True}
    )
```

**views**

```
def order_view(request):
    user_orders = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

How can I get all `order_item` values for each order?

```
{% for order in orders %}
    {% for ord in orderitem.order_set.all %}
        123
    {% endfor %}    
{% endfor %}
```

And how can I get all `product_item` for `order_item`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the OrderItems through the `related_name`:

```
{% for order in orders %}
    {% for item in order.order_item.all %}
        {{ item.pk }}
    {% endfor %}    
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Not sure about your second question, ```OrderItem``` can only point to one ```Product``` if you want to access that product in the template you just have to do ```{{ item.product_item }}```